# Django custom middleware get Anonymous user even after sending authenticated request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, middleware

I wanted to have an microservice ( say api_gateway - build in django ) which need to checks if the requested URL ( of microservice 2 ) from microservice 1 has the permission or not. The api_gateway project doesn't include the URL of microservice 2.

There are 2 solutions that I have come up with i.e.

1. custom permission
2. custom middleware

With custom permission, the permission is working fine, but response is sending 404 as the requested URL doesn't exists in api_gateway project. It exists in the microservice 2 project.

With custom middleware, I'm unable to get the authenticated user, which is making hard to check the request user permission.

For authentication method, I have implemented JWT Authentication using `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` library.

Settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'core.middleware.ReverseProxyMiddleware',
]

BY_PASS_URLS = ["/api/token/", "/api/token/refresh/", "/admin"]
```

custom_middleware.py

```
class ReverseProxyMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def process_request(self, request):

        print(request.user.is_authenticated)
        
        for each_path in settings.BY_PASS_URLS:
            if each_path in request.path:
                response = self.get_response(request)
                return response
        
        if self.check_permission(request):
            response = self.get_response(request)
            return response
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden("Permission denied")

    def check_permission(self, request):
         
        perm = APICheckPermission()
        return perm.has_permission(request)
```

logs

```
2023-12-09 17:43:34 False AnonymousUser
2023-12-09 17:43:34 Forbidden: /some_url
2023-12-09 17:43:34 [09/Dec/2023 17:43:34] "GET /some_url HTTP/1.1" 403 17
```

Response

```
Permission denied
```

models.py

```
class APIEndpoint(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    http_method = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    def _str_(self):
        return f"{self.http_method} {self.url}"
```

custom_permission.py

```
class APICheckPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission check for blocked IPs.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        print("permission check")
        url = request.path
        method = request.method

        print(url, method, request.user)
        if request.user.groups.filter(apiendpoint__url__icontains=url, apiendpoint__http_method__icontains=method).exists():
            return True
        return False
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

Comment: The authentication is handled *after* routing it: the Django REST framework handles this.

Comment: hi @willeM_VanOnsem so is there any way that I can add custom middleware with authenticated user ?

Comment: not with middleware no, but what you seem to be doing is a permission. Django's REST API has logic to check permissions: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ so that is likely what you aim to do, these run *after* the authentication process.

Comment: actually @willeM_VanOnsem i wanted to create an api gateway, i had implemented with permission before also, which was working, but the only issue is that in my project, I dont want to add urls, I just need to proxy the request to other domains if the authenticated user has the permission for the requested url. Hence with the permission, I get 404 error because the request url doesnot exists

Answer (score 0):

The authentication is handled *after* routing it, so *after* the middleware has been applied. Indeed, the `AuthenticationMiddleware` does *not* handle this. It is handled by Django's [**`authentication_classes`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

Control is thus passed to the view. The `dispatch()` method will then [*initialize the request* <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0f39e0124d358b0098261f070175fa8e0359b739/rest_framework/views.py#L485-L512):

> ```
>     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         # …
>         request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
>         self.request = request
>         # …
> ```

and this will [*run the authentication logic* <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0f39e0124d358b0098261f070175fa8e0359b739/rest_framework/views.py#L385-L397):

> ```
>     def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         """
>         Returns the initial request object.
>         """
>         parser_context = self.get_parser_context(request)
>
>         return Request(
>             request,
>             parsers=self.get_parsers(),
>             authenticators=self.get_authenticators(),
>             negotiator=self.get_content_negotiator(),
>             parser_context=parser_context
>         )
> ```

This will run Simple JWT authentication, or any other authentication you defined, and thus patch the request by setting a `.user` on the `request`. In some sense it thus duplicates the work of the `AuthenticationMiddleware`, but with a more customizable backend.

But very likely you *don't* need the middelware. What you here are doing is [checking *permissions* <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/). This is the next step in a `GenericAPIView`.

You thus can make your own permission class:

```
# app_name/permissions.py

from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class MyPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # …
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # …
        return True
```

and then plug that into your `GenericAPIView`:

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView


class MyGenericAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    # …
    permission_classes = [MyPermission]
    # …
```

you can add the permission by default to any `GenericAPIView` that does not define a custom permission with:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'app_name.permissions.MyPermission',
    ]
}
```

Comment: What I want to achieve is that I just need to create proxy server with django( api gateway ). Hence I want to redirect the user to the requested URL. But the requested URL doesn't exists in the django project. The project only used for proxing and authentication.

Comment: @PratikSharma: but your `ReverseProxyMiddleware` is not doing that: it essentially checks if the path is in the `BY_PASS_URLS`, if not, if the user permissions are valid, and finally if not, raises a permission denied. So that logic is easily transferrable to the permission checker: we check if the `view` is one of the one to bypass, if not, if it has the right permissions, and if not return `False`.

Comment: The flow is that I have multiple microservice, whenever 1 ms need to talk to another, api_gateway ( one more micoservice ) comes into the picture, which checks if the current logged in user ( from ms 1 ) has the permission to make request to the another  ms ( ms 2 ) or not. Hence the api_gateway ms havn't set the url's of ms 2. With custom permission checker, i'm getting 404 error whenever ms 2 makes request to ms1

Comment: @PratikSharma: but that is not how `response = self.get_response(request)` works, that is the same server: `get_response` is just a link to the "inner" handler, a method pointer that goes to the next middleware, and eventually the view. You don't make any HTTP requests to another service, it thus remains in the same service, and will eventually call the view it has already been routing to, or an underlying part of the middleware that will eventually call the view.

Comment: Okay. So can't we just create url based on microservice 2 url : Host + request_url and redirect request to URL.

I tried to return 
res = requests.get("https://www.google.com")
        return Response(
            data={},
            status=200
        )
this code from ReverseProxyMiddleware , but is giving me 
django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over. error

Comment: @PratikSharma: you can just use the `GenericViewSet` or some other view to check the credentials, permissions, and make a redirect. So you check if the user can pass through the gateway with the permission class, and then use the view to "forward" the request.

Comment: okay so there will be only one URL ( say /redirect ) where request will receive and the view will checks the permission and forward the request to some domain.
Hence this url, need to allow post call with data like  { "requested_url" : URL } ? right  ?